# Stack/Docker/IHaskell weird behaviour

Tags: haskell, docker, cabal, jupyter, ihaskell

I have a package with bunch of *.c and *.cpp files, listed inside `c-sources` field of `*.cabal` file. I need to include it inside a project with IHaskell and some other packages. Everything works fine, and builds without a problem. `stack exec ghci` works fine and I can import modules and execute any code. `stack ghci` though throws some weird errors, like this:

```
In file included from <command-line>:10:0: 

/...blabla.../.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.4.0/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h:157:0:
     note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define CURRENT_PACKAGE_KEY "blabla"
     ^
```

And `stack ghci` inside my package complains about symbols exported from its C code. Another weird thing is that symbols depend on the order of `exposed-modules` in the configuration, so the error goes away if I put my *.hs module on top of others, but if I have two *.hs files importing from the same *.c file, it won't work! `stack exec jupyter -- console --kernel haskell` starts, but immediately throws `unknown symbol` error if I try to run some code from my package, always the same though.

I have a docker image based on `fpco/stack-build`, which just installs jupyter and other necessary stuff. I use `lts-3.0` snapshot, if it's somehow relevant.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of improvements made recently to stack ghci, which is still mostly a work in progress. I'd recommend testing out stack master, and if the problem still exists opening a Github issue.